# Matlab str2func calling a mex file and getting input variable error

Tags: matlab

I have a mex-function specialRationalMap_00001.mexw64, that can be called without problems

```
vm = specialRationalMap_00001(vm,amplitude);
```

If I am trying to use the function name and str2func

```
f_str = 'specialRationalMap_00001';
fz = str2func(strcat('@(vm,amplitude)', f_str));
vm = fz(vm,amplitude);
```

I got the error: "A map input and a (scalar) amplitude required", but I am using exactly this as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont forget to actually pass the input arguments. Either do

```
fz = str2func(strcat('@(vm,amplitude)', f_str, '(vm,amplitude)'));
```

But better, you can just do:

```
fz = str2func(f_str);
```